# socket server - getting a connected user's ip

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver, python-sockets

I have just started to make a simple socket "chat" server where users connect to my server through `telnet`. I was wondering how I could get the connected users IP address so that It would print out that users message like so:

```
IP address: "Hello"
```

This is the code I am using so far:

```
def broadcast(self, message):
      for sessions in self.sessions:
          sessions.push('>>' + message + '\r\n')
```

Thanks in advance, If you need any more information please ask.

EDIT:

A link to the entire program: http://pastebin.com/9vzuiLZe

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? When you actually establish the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add to your code:

```
class ChatSession(async_chat):
    def __init__(self,server,sock):
        async_chat.__init__(self, sock)
        self.server = server
        self.set_terminator("\r\n")
        self.data = []
        self.sock = sock # <--- add this, so you remember the socket object
```

And then use what @staticd suggested:

```
def broadcast(self, line):
    for sessions in self.sessions:
        sessions.push(sessions.sock.getpeername() + ': ' + line + '\r\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, problem is Im getting this exception now: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple because the peername is displayed as (ip, socket) the , is causing errors. Think I could just use regex to extract just the ip

Comment: Use `sessions.push(sessions.sock.getpeername()[0] + ': ' + line + '\r\n')` perhaps?

Comment: As I said I am still a novice. I just used the tuple as if it were an array and user = sessions.sock.getpeername(); ip = user[0] :) This worked thanks

Answer (score 4):

`<your-socket-instance>.getpeername()` will give you what you want

Comment: Thanks, although this throws an exception: 'module' object has no attribute 'getpeername'

Comment: @DeanMWake not to be called on the module named `socket`, but on the actual socket which holds the connection (I know that the comment is old, but it had one upvote which is a problem).